# calculate difference between 2 column pairs (product/stock)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

In a google spreadsheet I have 2 column pairs, EAN + number in stock

Some EAN's are present in both column A and C, some only in column A column and some only in column B.

Eaxmple:

```
A               B   C               D  E              F
8573489753888   1   8729029847359   2  
8789026119040   1   8434234872389   1
8789026118692   3   8789026118609   2
8729029847359   1   8789026118692   1
```

I need to find EAN's present in both column A and C and calculate the stock difference (column B and D). The result should be listed in column E and F. 
I created a script that does this, but since I keep hitting the max execution time (the list is getting long), I am hoping this could be done without a script as well.

The results should be as follows:

```
A               B   C               D  E              F
8573489753888   1   8729029847359   2  8789026118692  2
8789026119040   1   8434234872389   1  8729029847359  -1
8789026118692   3   8789026118609   2
8729029847359   1   8789026118692   1
```

Comment: is it possible that A column or C column can have multiple same EANs?

Comment: no, both columns contain only unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### full diference:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:B; C1:C, D1:D*-1}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image]

- #### reverse:

  [image: 0]

---

### relevant diference:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:B, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, C1:D, 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2-Col3 
  where Col3 is not null 
  label Col2-Col3''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

- #### reverse:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution. I tried just with vlookup and it gets really complicated: `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E1;A:B;2;FALSE()));IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E1;C:D;2;FALSE()));0;VLOOKUP(E1;C:D;2;FALSE()));VLOOKUP(E1;A:B;2;FALSE())-IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E1;C:D;2;FALSE()));0;VLOOKUP(E1;C:D;2;FALSE()))`